# Which function in R would do a piecewise linear interpolation per each row, using other variables?

Tags: r, missing-data, linear-interpolation

Basically, I have this dataset with missing obs. So suppose we want to fill in missing data using the previous observation's Xs, and the average change for the Xs that exist for both the current and previous observation.

I'd expect this to be a common routine. Just don't know its name.

Added below is a 'manual' example:

```
data <- data.frame(A=1:4,
           B=c(21, 18, NA, NA),
           C=c(5:7,NA))
data

  A  B  C
1 1 21  5
2 2 18  6
3 3 NA  7
4 4 NA NA

for(i in 2:nrow(data)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(data)){
    if(is.na(data[i,j])){
      data[i,j] <- data[i-1,j]* 
       (sum(data[i,],na.rm=T))/sum(as.integer(!is.na(data[i,]))*data[i-1,])
    }
  }
}
 
data

  A    B        C
1 1 21.0 5.000000
2 2 18.0 6.000000
3 3 22.5 7.000000
4 4 30.0 9.333333
```

I can do it manually like provided. Just assuming it already exists.

I've updated a previous version, so that now it would to only affect NAs. Should be OK now.

Comment: Can you explain why the given values in columns A and C are changing?  I thought the problem is to replace the NA's and not recalculate the table.

Comment: So A2 is .963 because A1 * (row1 not A)/row1 = 0.963? Can you walk through the logic / meaning of what you're going for? I don't see what that has to do with linear interpolation.

Comment: Sorry, this shouldn't have happened. Yeah, the idea was to update NAs. Thanks for noticing that. I'll delete this question as it's phrased (the algorithm is probably also wrong).

Comment: @Dave2e, I've added an 'if' at the function. And updated the result. This should be OK now.

Comment: @JonSpring , I've added an 'if' at the function. And updated the result. This should be OK now.